# Try to use a command to Install login page?

Tags: php, laravel

I downloaded a project from Github and followed the instruction to open it for login in. I have to use `php artisan make:auth` but there is an error, how can you help me?

Comment: You need to share what the error is... this is the same as asking a doctor that you have pain somewhere and not sharing any more details and not allowing the doctor to even touch the zone in pain... how can we help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command is no longer available(Depends on the version ), use this:

```sh
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan migrate
```

source :
[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication)

Comment: It is not 100% true, it depends on what Laravel version the author is using

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes you are right but usually this is the problem he or she did not mention the error so this is the best answer that I can  provide

Comment: I understand and agree, that is why I did not downvote your answer

Comment: @matiaslauriti  So give me UPVOTE :D LoL

Comment: @abcd tnx it is working

Comment: @sdfgh Finally you are here , your welcome. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)